# Javascript: Add onkeydown event to prompt()

Tags: javascript, web, onkeydown

I was wondering that could it somehow be possible to add onkeydown event to prompt()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't becouse is a browser native dialog function and it is not available by the DOM.

You can achieve a similar effect with some external javascript library like [jQuery.Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
 or [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) and then attach to that event

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately No.

The `prompt()` dialog is a native dialog (not DOM driven) and not open to manipulation via JavaScript.